# How i can set Condition to show only those SMS having "Name" this ? with help of Cursor in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

Here i have imported all libraries .

Then i have applied loop to fetch SMS from phone.

but i want to display SMS which Contain Senders name (ex=alex)

How can i do so.

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView textView;
    private TextView textView2;
    String msgData = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textView=findViewById(R.id.textView);
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_SMS}, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
    }


    public void ReadSms(View view) {
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://sms"),null,null,null,null);
        int x=cursor.getCount();
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        for (int i =1;i<=x;i++){
            msgData += cursor.getString(2) + " ==> "+ cursor.getString(12)+" \n";
            textView.setText(msgData);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with the below code first get contact number of person using name the read message using contact number.

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    //pass name of person in place of "abc" in below line it will give you the contact number of that person
    String contactNo = getNumber("abc");

    // pass above contactNo variable in below line
    readMessageOfSpecificPerson(contactNo);
}

public String getNumber(String name) {
    String number = "";
    Uri uri = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
    String[] projection = new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER};
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    int indexName = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
    int indexNumber = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    do {
        String Name = cursor.getString(indexName);
        String Number = cursor.getString(indexNumber);
        if (Name.equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
            return Number.replace("-", "");
        }
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    if (!number.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
        return number.replace("-", "");
    } else return number;
}

private void readMessageOfSpecificPerson(String contactNo) {
    StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    String sms = "${Telephony.Sms.ADDRESS}=" + contactNo+" ";
    Uri SMS_INBOX = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(SMS_INBOX, null, sms, null, null);
    if (cursor != null) {
        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Telephony.Sms.ADDRESS));
 // In the below line getting message content
 String msg  
= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Telephony.Sms.BODY));
stringBuffer.append(msg+"\n");
            }
textView.setText(stringBuffer.toString());
        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: i want to add condition of name if name like alex exists display the SMS of alex only 
hope you understand sir

Comment: if you have name of person then get contact number of that person and read all sms using that contact number

Comment: yes i have name where should i put it in your code 
just beginner please help.

Comment: i have add comment in code let me know, now clear everything

Comment: and also need to display those message 
i didnt find the .setText() method

Comment: yes code is correct but how can i set this message into TextView

Comment: but message can be multiple on same contact number, do you need to show all sms on view

Comment: No only the latest one from the specific Contact name

Comment: latest one means unread message, but unread can be multiple

Comment: latest one means unreaded or readed 
it should be wrt Time or recent message

Comment: sir i just run the code with name but app is crashing (on emulator )
i dont know for what reason

Answer (score 0):

In your for-loop of ReadSms method, simply check if sender name exists before appending to your "msgData" String.

Comment: Can you please help me with code .
because i have already tried i think .

Comment: I believe Dharmender Manral, in the other answer, got it absolutely right. If the app is still crashing like you said it was, you need to check the error message and debug your program step by step. May I ask what the error message is? It would also be nice if you could show me your entire project. Maybe add a link to your GitHub repo of the project?